# Converting integer from 0 to 255 ( 1 byte ) into NSDATA

Tags: ios, byte, nsdata, typeconverter

I need exactly 1 byte for some kind of socket based application and i cant find a way to create it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
unsigned char mydata = 3;
[NSMutableData dataWithBytes:&mydata length:sizeof(mydata)];
```

NSData [reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/Reference/Reference.html), `unsigned char` is used to save 1 byte.